# Maclaurin Series for $x^3 \sin{2x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I find the Maclaurin Series for $x^3 \sin{2x}$? If I start differenciating, I get 2 terms like $2x^3 \cos{2x} + \sin{2x}\cdot 3x^2$ then 4 for the next one. Is this the right way to go?

I just need to find $f^{(2012)}(0)$ of $f(x)= x^3\cdot \sin{2x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $$\sin x=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\;;\tag{1}$$ to get $\sin 2x$, just substitute $2x$ for $x$ in $(1)$, and to get $x^3\sin 2x$, follow that up by multiplying by $x^3$. Then you need only figure out what the coefficient of $x^{2012}$ is.

Comment: Hmm ... so $x^3 \sin{2x} = \sum \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n+1}(x^3)}{(2n+1)!}$? If so why don't I need to differenciate $x^3$ like what I need before I get the maclaurin series for $\sin$?

Comment: @JiewMeng: That’s right; and you can simplify $(2x)^{2n+1}x^3$ to $2^{2n+1}$ times what power of $x$?

Comment: I got $x^3 \sin{2x} = \sum \frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n+1} x^2n+4}{(2n+1)!}$. How do I get rid of the $x^{2n+4}$ before I find $f^{(2012)}(0)$? In a prev problem I canceled it with $x^n$. Else I will have $f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n+1} x^{2+4/n} n!}{(2n+1)!}$

Comment: @JiewMeng: You want the coefficient of $x^{2012}$. For what value of $n$ is $2n+4=2012$? What is the coefficient of that term? You’ll **never** have powers of $x$ in $f^{(n)}(0)$: that’s just a number.

Comment: The question asks to find $f^{(2012)}(0)$. So if I used $2012 = 2n+4, \qquad n = 1004$ It doesn't appear correct?

Comment: @JiewMeng: The $x^{2012}$ term is indeed the one for which $n=1004$: it’s $$\frac{(-1)^{1004}}{2009!}x^{2012}\;,$$ so the coefficient of $x^{2012}$ is $$\frac1{2009!}\;.$$ The coefficient of $x^{2012}$ in the Maclaurin series for $f$ is $$\frac{f^{(2012)}(0)}{2012!}\;.$$ When you equate these, what do you get for $f^{(2012)}(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, just a few hints:

- Find the series $T(x)$ for $\sin x$ around $x=0$.
- Evaluate $T(x)$ at $2x$ and simplify so it looks like another Taylor/Maclaurin series.
- Multiply $T(2x)$ by $x^3$ to obtain the series for $x^3\sin(2x)$.

For more examples, see [this Planetmath page](https://planetmath.org/ExamplesOnHowToFindTaylorSeriesFromOtherKnownSeries).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find $f^{(2012)}(0)$, then a good choice may be [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) for differentiating a product $n$ times. Note that your formula will end at $k=3$.

Comment: Your answer will be something like $3!\binom{2012}{3}(\sin 2x)^{(2009)}(0)=..$

Comment: Thanks @Brian M. Scott for fixing the link.